# Empty MacBook Pro, no SuperDrive. How do I install Windows?

Tags: windows, usb, installation, macbook

My situation is this:

- HDD1: Empty 180 GB SSD
- HDD2: Empty 500 GB HDD (instead of SuperDrive)

Accessories:

- Windows 8 ISO
- 64 Gig USB stick
- Second computer
- SuperDrive in USB enclosure

What I need:

- Install Windows 8 on the SSD in the laptop

What I tried:

- Create bootable USB – Doesn't work. Macbook doesnt show me USB as an option after holding OPTION key.
- Install Windows through SuperDrive connected via USB – Doesn't work.

On the internet, there are thousands of articles telling me all kinds of solutions, expecting me to have Mac OS on my laptop. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: looks interesting. but it should work in either way. is your USB is formatted in  HFS+ or FAT32 ?

Comment: This sounds like a localized configuration problem.;

Answer (score 1):

Can you find an external computer & install via the Windows USB Tool?

I did it this way

http://windowswise.com/windows-8-usb-installation/

Answer (score 0):

Due to lack of driver support and Windows issues with the Mac BIOS & EFI, you will run into challenges trying to install Windows by itself. (example: http://derekhat.com/install-vista-on-a-macbook-without-bootcamp/).

The recommended approach is to use Parallels, Bootcamp, or some other means of Virtualization.  Here is an article describing how they did it - and apparently you get native or near-native (Windows) performance:

http://www.theverge.com/2012/2/10/2787484/macbook-air-with-windows-7-review-the-ultrabook-to-rule-them-all